# d3js choropleth won't fill

Tags: d3.js, choropleth

I am able to draw a map of China with d3js but the choropleth won't fill. The code:

```
<script>
var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
    width = parseInt(d3.select('#map').style('width')),
    height = width*0.7;

var places = <?php echo json_encode($provinces); ?> 

var minimum = d3.min(places, function(d) { return d.rate; }),
    maximum = d3.max(places, function(d) { return d.rate; });

var minimumColor = "#BFD3E6", 
    maximumColor = "#88419D";

var color = d3.scale
    .linear()
    .domain([minimum, maximum])
    .range([minimumColor, maximumColor]);

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([109, 31])
    .scale(width*0.85)
    .translate([width/1.8, height/1.5])

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

d3.json("data/china_simplify.json", function(error, root) {

    if (error) 
    return console.error(error);
    console.log(root.features);

    var rateById = {};
    places.forEach(function(d) { rateById[d.id] = +d.rate; });

    console.log(rateById);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "provinces")
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data( root.features )
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path )
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(rateById[d.id]); });

});
</script>
```

As you can see, I have included `console.log(rateById);`, which returns:

```
Object {1: 5829, 2: 2181, 3: 33904, 4: 14182, 5: 23290, 6: 135365, 7: 56757, 8: 21148, 9: 463618, 10: 1895, 11: 8408, 12: 12318, 13: 2990, 14: 25601, 15: 12720, 16: 41816, 17: 27993, 18: 47288, 19: 15422, 20: 24968, 21: 34515, 22: 36199, 23: 44708, 24: 20886, 25: 16609, 26: 70220, 27: 117876, 28: 84413, 29: 14271, 30: 23102, 31: 19010, 32: 16097, 33: 3783, 34: 7616}
```

The key refers to the ID of the province. Here is a snippet of the `china_simplify.json` file:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":1,"name":"甘肃"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[104.35851932200904,37.40123159456249],[104.46450768428224,37.440247301072134],[104.68950687084538,37.41192861571304],[104.76474775590418,37.25049144112714],[104.92241255059872,37.096754055055584],[105.18017459508144,36.97213633912071], [...]
```

Not sure why it isn't filling properly! If I remove the `return color(rateById[d.id]);` and replace with `red` then everything is filled red. This suggests that the problem is related to the `color` function.

**EDIT**

When I run `console.log( color(rateById[1]) );` it returns `#bfd2e5`. This suggests that there is nothing wrong with the `color` function itself, but for some reason the hex codes aren't being filled in the map.

There's probably something wrong here: `.style("fill", function(d) { return color(rateById[d.id]); })`. I can't seem to figure it out because it matches [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3306362).

**EDIT 2**

I've put together a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o06edvuf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I found it.

```
.style("fill", function(d) { 
        return color(rateById[d.properties.id]); })
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that fixed it. Out of curiously, why do you need `properties`?

Comment: print d, you will know.

Answer (score 1):

In rateById, rates are aggregated over id, but the domain is set considering min and max rate. Set the domain for color using rateById:

```
var minimum = d3.min(d3.values(rateById)),
maximum = d3.max(d3.values(rateById));
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, as the color function works fine. See my edits above. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can u create a fiddle?